# Hierarchy in declearing Media Queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In these days I had an issue with media queries:
at first I created two separate CSS, one for the styling, and one for the media queries, but it doesnt't work properly, it doesn't do anything on any browsers;
So I put all my CSS in a single file and it works now.

1 - So my first question is, what are the best "place" to declear my media queries?

The second issue I had is that I needed to change the padding properties, which were declared close at the top of my CSS. When I wondered to change this properties with MediaQuery it didn't do nothing.
So I move them from the top of my css close to the media queries and now it's working.

2 - My second question is, do exist an Hierarchy of declearing css classes and IDs when you have to work with media queries?

3 - Could this problems be in the `<head>` section?

( If you have some resources that I could read, it could help everybody who want to clarify this questions. Thanks in advance!! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it sounds like you may have some issues with specificity, and ordering.

Things to remember:

- Browsers will always prefer a more specific rule than a general rule (a `p.link{}` rule is more specific than a `p{}` rule, and thus would overwrite any shared properties)
- Browsers generally render CSS 'down the page', meaning that the last defined property will overwrite any previously written property. In other words, if you're including two stylesheets, make sure that your media queries stylesheet is included second, if you want its rules to take priority.

To answer the questions:

1) The 'best place' is really a style thing. Some favor separate stylesheets to keep things neat, others favor inside the rules themselves to keep things concise. As long as they appear after your normal rules, you should be in the clear.

2) The code inside a media query should work exactly like code that isn't in a media query. There's no difference in hierarchy.

3) It's hard to say without seeing your code.

Great CSS resources for :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Cascading_and_inheritance
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

1. That's subjective
2. The rules for [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) are unaltered by media queries
3. Since CSS (other than style attributes) must go inside the `head` element, presumably that is where your CSS is and so presumably that is where your problems are.